# Filter data according to number of observations for each name

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

This table is a simplified version of the one I have.
Now that I have multiple observations for each user, I want to include specific ones. The rule I want to apply is that if the observation for a specific user is just one observation, then include this one observation, else, include the 2nd observation only (as ordered by time for each session played).

| name | user_id | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e_1 | 111 | 101 |
| e_1 | 111 | 102 |
| e_1 | 111 | 103 |
| e_2 | 112 | 104 |
| e_2 | 112 | 105 |
| e_3 | 113 | 106 |
| e_3 | 113 | 107 |
| e_4 | 114 | 108 |
| e_5 | 115 | 109 |

**So, I want to reach this output**

| name | user_id | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e_1 | 111 | 102 |
| e_2 | 112 | 105 |
| e_3 | 113 | 107 |
| e_4 | 114 | 108 |
| e_5 | 115 | 109 |

I tried running multiple codes that use dplyr, and use if_else. I used the function count() to find the number of observations for each name, and then tried to filter accordingly

**Here's my try**

```
new_table<- 
old_table %>%
group_by(name) %>%
arrange(name) %>% 
if_else(count(name) %>% filter(n==1), filter (row_number()==1), filter (row_number()==2))
```

**However it's not working. Kindly guide me to adjust it for the right code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidyverse option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~name, ~user_id, ~session_id,
  "e_1", 111, 101,
  "e_1", 111, 102,
  "e_1", 111, 103,
  "e_2", 112, 104,
  "e_2", 112, 105,
  "e_3", 113, 106,
  "e_3", 113, 107,
  "e_4", 114, 108,
  "e_5", 115, 109
) |> 
  group_by(user_id) |> 
  filter(row_number() <= 2) |> 
  slice_tail(n = 1)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Groups:   user_id [5]
#>   name  user_id session_id
#>   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 e_1       111        102
#> 2 e_2       112        105
#> 3 e_3       113        107
#> 4 e_4       114        108
#> 5 e_5       115        109
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello Carl, thank you for your prompt reply,

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient, but should give you a solution.

Input Data:

```
> df
  name user_id session_id
1  e_1     111        101
2  e_1     111        102
3  e_1     111        103
4  e_2     112        104
5  e_2     112        105
6  e_3     113        106
7  e_3     113        107
8  e_4     114        108
9  e_5     115        109
```

And then:

```
rnam.df <- c()
for (n in unique(df$name)){
  new_df <- subset(df,df$name==n) # subset df by names
  ifelse(nrow(new_df)>1,Value <- 2, Value <- 1) # you only want first or second row whith same name
  rnam.df <- append(rnam.df,row.names(new_df[Value, ])) # append row names which contains the values found
}
```

Out:

```
> rnam.df
[1] "2" "5" "7" "8" "9"

> df[rnam.df, ]
  name user_id session_id
2  e_1     111        102
5  e_2     112        105
7  e_3     113        107
8  e_4     114        108
9  e_5     115        109
```

**EDIT**

3rd column should not be a problem since I did not work with. I got values from previous post before you made the edit!